# How to estimate the complex integral along the vertical side?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In a complex integral related question, I have difficulty in trying to find the estimation of the integral along the vertical side.

The integral is
\begin{equation}
\int_{L_{R}} \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}}{z} \mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
where the line segment $L_{R}$ is $z=R+iy, R>0, 0\leq y\leq R$. I want to find the limit of it when $R$ goes to infinity.
My attempt is as follows
\begin{equation}
\left\vert\int_{L_{R}} \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}}{z} \mathrm{d}z\right\vert=\left\vert\int_{0}^{R} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(R^2-y^2+2iRy)}}{R+iy}i\mathrm{d}y\right\vert\leq\frac{1}{R}\int_{0}^{R}e^{-\frac{R^2}{2}}e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}\mathrm{d}y\leq\frac{1}{R}\times R=1
\end{equation} which is weird.

How to find the estimation order of $R$ when it goes to infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{R}\int_{0}^{R}e^{-\frac{R^2}{2}}e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}\mathrm{d}y\le \frac{1}{R}\int_{0}^{R}e^{-\frac{R^2}{2}}e^{\frac{Ry}{2}}\mathrm{d}y$. Now compute the integral to finish the proof.